# wowza ec-2 cloudfront costing

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudfront, http-live-streaming, wowza

We are planning to host wowza media server with 55 $ monthly charges and take aws instance m1.large along with cloud front support. Use case is we are planning HTTP streaming ( in rare cases RTMP too ). But before going ahead we are not able to concur on costing as it involves multiple variables.

- Say we want to stream video of 360p for 400 users every day for 8 hours ( all concurrent) for a month is it going to support & if yes what would be cost?This is classroom scenario where tutor is delivering lecture to students.
- If change it 240p and 720p how much cost would vary ?

Would appreciate if we get exact cost for server+ bandwidth estimates(data flow though data is going to be in same region for AWS) ( considering standard encoding)?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, unfortunately multiple variables are involved. First, you need to know what bitrate your video is (240p and 720p don't specify bitrates). The choice of server you make will also affect your pricing, not to mention your maximum concurrent bandwidth.

The  [Wowza Forums](http://www.wowza.com/forums/forum.php) are a good place to look for discussions about server configurations and throughput. AWS has all the pricing for the different servers, as well as pricing for CloudFront.

I'd suggest starting with calculating your min/max bandwidth requirements, then use that to look at your server choices. Then, factor in your CloudFront costs based on usage. And don't forget storage if needed- either an S3 bucket or some EBS volumes on your Wowza server.

The [AWS cost calculator](http://calculator.s3.amazonaws.com/index.html) might be of some help, too.